# SQL - Matching data across 2 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in an MS SQL server Db:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTable](
    [Sequence] [int] NULL,
    [Text] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and here is my data

```
Sequence    Text
1           Hello     
2           World     
3           Hello     
4           Dave      
5           Hello     
6           Suzanne
```

Requirement: I need to return a True or false if my dataset contains a sequence of words, for example:

- search for "Hello Dave" returns True
- Search for "Hello Foo" returns False

I've got to here:

```
SELECT [sequence] ,[Text]
FROM [dbo].[testTable]

where text in ('hello', 'dave')
```

which gives me:

```
Sequence Text
1        Hello     
3        Hello     
4        Dave      
5        Hello
```

My question is how to then query this data set to check for the numbers being next to them

Thanks!

Comment: Clarification: Do the two words need to be in any order and/or in consecutive records, or they just need to be somewhere in the table? Also, as you asking seeking a solution with and only two words, or there may be more?

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @FDavidov hello, there will be N number of words and they will need to be in consecutive order which the user specifies

Comment: IN that case, though it may be possible to implement this with a single (rather complex) query, the best and most maintainable solution would require some additional coding. If SQL Server would support Arrays, then the solution would be trivial (but, unfortunately, it does not). Let me know if you are up to add some coding and I'll give you the guidelines.

Comment: Hi @FDavidov, I'm going to be running the query through entity framework from C#, so i've got code to work with this issue as well

Comment: What about implementing a simple stored procedure/function that would do the job for you and return the result as required (TRUE/FALSE)? is that an option?

Comment: @FDavidov, yes I'm able to use Store procs and views to complete this

Comment: Great!!! DO you need some guidance or you can manage alone?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170347/discussion-between-mr-giggles-and-fdavidov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really view this as two separate questions, one which answers whether the words exist, and the other which finds the possible id values.  For the first, we can aggregate over the entire table:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT text) = 2 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS status
FROM testTable
WHERE text IN ('hello', 'dave');
```

Trivially, if you want the sequence numbers of the matching keywords, assuming the above query reveals that those words are all present, you may just use:

```
SELECT Sequence
FROM testTable
WHERE text IN ('hello', 'dave');
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

One method is a `join`:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from testtable w1 join
     testtable w2
     on w1.sequence = w2.sequence + 1
where w2.text = 'Hello' and w2.text = 'Dave';
```

Comment: That would be ok as long as there are only two words. I smell that the OP needs something more generic (though he might be too far away or my smelling sense misleading me).

Comment: @FDavidov . . . Just to be explicit, more joins would need to be added for each word.